# Part of game theory to check

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I want to model this problem: I have two captains that have to choose between other people to built two different teams, obviously both prefer to choose firstly their "friends". Which part of game theory is that? I can't find any solution searching on google.

Thanks to all!

Comment: The question is quite vague. Can you add more details as to how exactly this process works please?

Comment: It sounds like problems relating to drafting players in sports. I guess it was studied, but can't recall a paper right away from the top of my head.